# Load ajax modal only the modal is not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax modal that loads every 5 min. But at this moment it keeps loading it even if the previous modal is open. How can i prevent the modal from opening again but only if the previous one is closed

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('*[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').click();}
,300000);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="modal.html" data-toggle="ajaxModal">open modal</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your set interval code as follows:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if($('#ajaxModal').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') return;

    $('*[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').click();
}
,300000);
```

Because when the dialog is open the `#ajaxModal` shadow item sets its `aria-hidden` attribute to `true`.